# Collecting Coins using singletons in Godot 4.1.1

Tags: godot, godot4

I am making a 3d endless runner game. but the problem lies in collecting the coin.
I want to display the coins that are collected by the player.

This is my label script:
[image]
This is my Globalscript:
[image]
This is my Coin script:
[image]

I was expecting that if i collected a coin. my coin display would display how many coins I have collected.

so far, my collision shapes and the coin detect each other as it shows "collected" on my output :
[image]

but in game, it does not display that I collected it:
[image]

Comment: Is the on_body_entered function of the label is acutally called, or do you just use GlobalScript.emit_signal somewhere else? Your code should work, if the function is actually called, even if it is odd to me, to call the _ready function again (move the setting text in a seperate call or as an answer suggested use a setter. Produces cleaner code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I gather there are two "body_entered" signals:

- `Global_Coin` (I'm taking it is an autoload) has a `_on_body_entered` signal defined, which passes no arguments:

  ```
  extends Node

  signal _on_body_entered
  ```

  Then in your `Area3D` you connect it to the `_on_body_entered` method.

  And it would be emitted by the `Label` of all things, from the `_on_body_entered` method which I believe is not called at all.
- The `Area3D` has a `body_entered` that has a `body:Node3D` parameter.

  This signal would be emitted by the `Area3D` when some body enters it.

  And I'm guessing is connected to the `_on_body_entered` method by other means, which explains how the `"collected"` message shows up in output.

Note: I'm confident that the `body_entered` signal of the `Area3D` is not connected to the `_on_body_entered` of the `Label` because that method has no parameters, and thus you would have an error if it were connected, given that the `body_entered` signal from `Area3D` passes an argument.

---

Thus:

1. Pick different names for different things. Otherwise you will end up confusing whoever reads your code, which most of the time is yourself (which I believe is the case here).
2. Single responsibility principle: The job of the `Label` is to display text. Why is the `Label` responsible from emitting a signal (and of "body entered" of all things)? It should not be emitting a signal for this (that is not its responsibility). In fact, it makes more sense that it would be receiving it.

---

The following is what makes sense:

1. Make sure the `body_entered` signal of the `Area3D` is connected to the `_on_body_entered` method in the scrip attached to the same `Area3D`. *I believe this is already the case, but I do not see the usual green icon that indicates the connection, thus I suggest to double check.*
2. Have the `_on_body_entered` method in the `Area3D` emit the `_on_body_entered` signal from `Global_Coin`. *In fact, I'd suggest to change the name of the signal to something more meaningful, e.g. `coin_collected`.*
3. Connect from code the `_on_body_entered` signal from `Global_Coin` to the `_on_body_entered` method in the `Label` (currently you do this in the `Area3D`), so the `Label` can increment its count.

In general the flow of data would be like this:

- Godot detects the collision, and tells the `Area3D`
- The `Area3D` emits its `Area3D.body_entered` signal.
- The `Area3D` handles the `Area3D.body_entered` signal, and emits the `Global_Coin._on_body_entered` signal, *and also queues itself from removal*.
- The Label handles the `Global_Coin._on_body_entered` signal and increments its count. *I'll insist in renaming the singal.*

Furthermore, we can put a setter on `coins` instead of calling `_ready`.

Thus:

*Global_Coin*:

```
extends Node

signal coin_collected
```

*Area3D*:

```
extends Area3D

func _on_body_entered(body:Node3D) -> void:
    prints("collected")
    Global_Coin.coin_collected.emit()
    queue_free()
```

*Label*:

```
extends Label


var coins:int = 0:
    set (mod_value):
        coins = mod_value
        text = str(coins)


func _ready() -> void:
    Global_Coin.coin_collected.connected(_on_coin_collected)
    # coins = 0


func _on_coin_collected() -> void:
    coins = coins + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was very crispy clear and concise! 
I was stuck and still inexperienced in writing my codes that's why it is messy ahehe.

but thank you, sir. it works!

Answer (score 0):

To update a label, you need to update it's `text` field. It won't automatically detect changes to variables it was *originally* constructed with.

```
func on_body_entered() -> void:
    coins += 1
    text = str(coins)
    ...
```

You can automate this with a setter on the field.

```
var coins = 0:
    set(value):
        coins = value
        text = str(coins)

func on_body_entered() -> void:
    self.coins += 1
    ...
```

We need `self.coins` so as to trigger our own setter. Setting the variable directly bypasses it. But this has the advantage that, whenever anybody anywhere sets the `coins` variable, the label will update alongside it.

The above syntax is for Godot 4. If you're still on Godot 3, it looks like this.

```
var coins = 0 setget _set_coins

func _set_coins(value):
    coins = value
    text = str(coins)

func on_body_entered() -> void:
    self.coins += 1
    ...
```

Comment: the thing is, that he does call text = str(coins) but in a wierd way. on_body_entered calls _ready() again, which in turn calls  text = str(coins)